# Spark SQL weekofyear function

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark sql's `weekofyear` function to calculate the week number for the given date.

I am using the following code,

```
test("udf - week number of the year") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("udf - week number of the year").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val data1 = Seq("20220101", "20220102", "20220103", "20220104", "20220105", "20220106", "20220107", "20220108", "20220109", "20220110", "20220111", "20220112")
    data1.toDF("day").createOrReplaceTempView("tbl_day")
    spark.sql("select day, to_date(day, 'yyyyMMdd') as date, weekofyear(to_date(day, 'yyyyMMdd')) as week_num from tbl_day").show(truncate = false)

    /*
          +--------+----------+--------+
      |day     |date      |week_num|
      +--------+----------+--------+
      |20220101|2022-01-01|52      |
      |20220102|2022-01-02|52      |
      |20220103|2022-01-03|1       |
      |20220104|2022-01-04|1       |
      |20220105|2022-01-05|1       |
      |20220106|2022-01-06|1       |
      |20220107|2022-01-07|1       |
      |20220108|2022-01-08|1       |
      |20220109|2022-01-09|1       |
      |20220110|2022-01-10|2       |
      |20220111|2022-01-11|2       |
      |20220112|2022-01-12|2       |
      +--------+----------+--------+
     */
    spark.stop
  }
```

I am surprised to find that 20220101's week number is 52, but it is the first day of 2022, so that it should be 1.

I instigate the source code of `weekofyear` and find:

It is using the following code to create the Calendar instance so that it gives the result above

```
  @transient private lazy val c = {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance(DateTimeUtils.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
    c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)
    c
  }
```

I would ask why spark sql treat the first few days of the year in this way.

As a comparison,

1. I using the following oracle sql to get the week number which gives me `1`

   select to_number(to_char(to_date('01/01/2022','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')) from dual
2. In hive, the result is the same as spark sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will post my findings here:

Spark SQL and Hive are following ISO-8601 standard to calculate the week number of the year for a given date.

One point to note: Spark SQL internally is using `java.util.Calendar` API to do the work , java 8' `java.time` API has been natively supporting ISO-8601 standard,using java.time API, we don't have to do the trick(`c.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)`)

Comment: Is there any way to change the start day of the year and week for this method.

Comment: I don't think so. To change the behavior, have to write a new UDF.

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to get the week of month out of a timestamp with date_format(dt_col, 'W') but the default week starts on Sun, is there any way to change this to start on Monday instead? Im on spark 2.4

Answer (score 3):

On Spark 3.0 you can use `EXTRACT` function. A few examples:

```
> SELECT extract(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-08-12 01:00:00.123456');
 2019
> SELECT extract(week FROM timestamp'2019-08-12 01:00:00.123456');
 33
> SELECT extract(doy FROM DATE'2019-08-12');
 224
> SELECT extract(SECONDS FROM timestamp'2019-10-01 00:00:01.000001');
 1.000001
> SELECT extract(days FROM interval 1 year 10 months 5 days);
 5
> SELECT extract(seconds FROM interval 5 hours 30 seconds 1 milliseconds 1 microseconds);
 30.001001
```

Documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#extract)